# expo-secure-store’s SecureStore.setItemAsync and getItemAsync not working with JEST

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, react-native-testing-library

This question is specifically about `expo-secure-store` and jest.

I am using `expo-secure-store` to store user's access_token when logging in. It works fine when running on device / simulator. But doesn't work at all in Jest tests; token comes back as undefined. I am able to call the functions like normal.

```
    test('Test SecureStore wrt Jest', async () => {
        try {
            await SecureStore.setItemAsync(TOKEN, 'randomToken');
            const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(TOKEN);
            console.log(token);
            expect(token).toBeDefined();
            expect(token).toBe(randomToken);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        }
   }
```

Package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react-native": "10.1.1",
        "expo": "^44.0.0",
        "jest": "28.1.2",
        "jest-expo": "^45.0.1",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-native": "0.64.3",
        "ts-jest": "^28.0.0-next.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jest": "^28.1.5",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    }
}
```

Here is mock file

```
jest.mock('expo-secure-store', () => {
  const realConstants = jest.requireActual('expo-constants').default
  const mockConstants = Object.create(realConstants)
  const realExpoSecureStore = jest.requireActual(
    'expo-secure-store/src/SecureStore'
  )
  const realExpoModulesCore = jest.requireActual(
    'expo-modules-core/src/NativeModulesProxy'
  )
  return {
    ...realConstants,
    ...realExpoSecureStore,
    ...realExpoModulesCore,
    mockConstants,
    NativeModulesProxy: {
      ExpoSecureStore: {
        setValueWithKeyAsync: jest.fn(),
        getValueWithKeyAsync: jest.fn(),
      },
    },
    SecureStore: {
      setItemAsync: jest.fn(),
      getItemAsync: jest.fn(),
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: I think this similar question has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66341640/868159

Comment: By any chance did you find a solution @Supria ?